# Show AlertController only one time - Ionic 2 AngularJS 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, dialog, ionic2

I added a really basic `AlertController` in my project in order to give the user a quick introduction to the app but, as its purpose is purely to welcome, I'd like to show it once (the first time the app is opened) so that future times there'll be none.

I included it in `ionViewWillEnter()` method:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Title',
      subTitle: 'Subtitle',
      message: 'Message',
      buttons: ['OK'],
      enableBackdropDismiss: false
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

As a starter in cross-platform development it's the first time I'm facing this problematic or rather what in Android is called SharedPreferences. I've looked at the official documentation of [AlertController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/alert/AlertController/) but I didn't find very much about the `handler` inside `buttons`.

This is what I do on Android to save the preference:

```
mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    Boolean welcomeScreenShown = mPrefs.getBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, false);

    if (!welcomeScreenShown) {

       AlertDialog.Builder(this)
          .setTitle("Title")
          .setMessage("Message")
          .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, true);
        editor.commit(); // Very important to save the preference
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify you problem, as far as it's written it's no possible to say that you were asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like other SO users mentioned, you could use Ionic Storage for doing that. First add it to the `providers` list in your `NgModule` declaration (for example, in `src/app.module.ts`):

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
    Storage
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then you'll need to inject it in the page where you show the alert and use it like this:

```
import { Component, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    constructor(..., private storage: Storage) {
        // ...
    }

    ionViewWillEnter() {
      this.storage.get('alreadyShown').then((alreadyShown) => {
         if(!alreadyShown) {
           this.storage.set('alreadyShown', true);
           this.showWelcomeAlert();
         }
      });
    }

    private showWelcomeAlert(): void {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Title',
        subTitle: 'Subtitle',
        message: 'Message',
        buttons: ['OK'],
        enableBackdropDismiss: false
      });
      alert.present();
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently `src/app.module.ts` looks like this: `providers: [provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]`. When I add Storage `providers: [Storage, provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]` I get a _Runtime Error: caused by: No provider for Storage!_. It does not work with just `providers: [Storage]` because the dialog is not displayed

Comment: I think you missed one `{`, it should be `providers: [Storage, { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]`

Comment: Perfect! I couldn't see it working because I was already deploying on the browser. I tried on the AVD and it works great! Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can save somewhere in a persistant storage that you have already showed the AlertController.

For example, you can use the `Secure Storage` to store a variable that is set when you show the AlertController.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ionic storage [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/)

and then make sure to set a value indicating that the alert was shown in the alert's handler.